# Get standard deviation for a GridSearchCV

Tags: python, scikit-learn, data-science, cross-validation, grid-search

Before scikit-learn 0.20 we could use `result.grid_scores_[result.best_index_]` to get the standard deviation. (It returned for exemple: `mean: 0.76172, std: 0.05225, params: {'n_neighbors': 21}`)

What's the best way in scikit-learn 0.20 to get the standard deviation of the best score ?

Answer (score 14):

In newer versions, the `grid_scores_` is renamed as `cv_results_`. Following the [documentation](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.model_selection.GridSearchCV.html), you need this:

> ```
> best_index_ : int
>
> The index (of the cv_results_ arrays) which corresponds to the best > 
>   candidate parameter setting.
>
> The dict at search.cv_results_['params'][search.best_index_] gives the > 
>   parameter setting for the best model, that gives the highest mean
>   score (search.best_score_).
> ```

So in your case, you need

- Best params :- `result.cv_results_['params'][result.best_index_]` OR `result.best_params_`
- Best mean score :- `result.cv_results_['mean_test_score'][result.best_index_]` OR `result.best_score_`
- Best std :- `result.cv_results_['std_test_score'][result.best_index_]`