# GridSearchCV not getting std scores on the cv_results dictionary?

Tags: python-3.x, scikit-learn, standard-deviation, gridsearchcv

until recently I was using GridSearchCV to get the std scores on the crossvalidation by doing this pointed in [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49099293/get-standard-deviation-for-a-gridsearchcv)

So basically doing this

```
grid_search.cv_results_['std_test_score'][grid_search.best_index_]
```

But now I get a key error telling me that 'std_test_score' is not a key.

This is how I call the GridSearchCV function

```
splitter = StratifiedKFold(n_splits=5, shuffle=True, random_state=11)


scoring_functions = {'mcc': make_scorer(matthews_corrcoef), 'accuracy': make_scorer(accuracy_score), 
                     'balanced_accuracy': make_scorer(balanced_accuracy_score)}

grid_search = GridSearchCV(pipeline, param_grid=grid, scoring=scoring_functions, n_jobs=-1, cv=splitter, refit='mcc')
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From [the documentation](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.model_selection.GridSearchCV.html), the `cv_results_` attribute description:

> For multi-metric evaluation, the scores for all the scorers are available in the `cv_results_` dict at the keys ending with that scorer's name (`'_<scorer_name>'`) instead of `'_score'` shown above. ('split0_test_precision', 'mean_train_precision' etc.)

You can get there pretty easily on your own, with `grid_search.cv_results_.keys()` to see what's available.  It ought to be e.g. `grid_search.cv_results_['std_test_mcc']`.

Comment: Yeah I just finished looking into the keys and came here to write the solution but you beat me to it. Thx!